# MongoDB Explain plan - elapsed time breakdown for executionStats

Tags: query-performance, mongodb, execution-plan, explain

I have run an explain plan for a query, and am a bit confused with the timings of each stage, and how they aggregate to the total elapsed time.

Following command was run to generate the statistics, verbosity mode set to executionStats Mode.

```
expStats = db.testdb.explain("executionStats")

expStats.aggregate([
    {"$match": {
        "Id": {"$in": ["AAA", "BBB"]},
        "testType":"TEST",
        }
    },
    {"$group": {
        "_id": {"Id":"$Id", "testType": "$testType", "testSubType":"$testSubType"},
        "count": {"$sum": 1}
        }
        }
    ])
```

A summary of the executionStats as follows:

```
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 6355196,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 17575,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 6355196,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "PROJECTION_COVERED",
        "nReturned" : 6355196,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 3464,
        "works" : 6355197,
        "advanced" : 6355196,
        "needTime" : 0,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 50390,
        "restoreState" : 50390,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "transformBy" : {
            "Id" : 1,
            "testSubType" : 1,
            "testType" : 1,
            "_id" : 0
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned" : 6355196,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 3251,
            "works" : 6355197,
            "advanced" : 6355196,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 50390,
            "restoreState" : 50390,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "keyPattern" : {
                        "Id" : 1,
                        "testType" : 1,
                        "eventTimestamp" : -1,
                        "testSubType" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "clientEvents",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "Id" : [ ],
                        "testType" : [ ],
                        "eventTimestamp" : [ ],
                        "testSubType" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "keysExamined" : 6355196,
                "seeks" : 1,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0
            }
        }
    }
},
{
"$group" : {
    "_id" : {
            "Id" : "$Id",
            "testType" : "$testType",
            "testSubType" : "$testSubType"
    },
    "count" : {
            "$sum" : {
                    "$const" : 1
            }
    }
}
}
```

The total execution time time = "executionTimeMillis" : 17575.

STAGE 1 (PROJECTION_COVERED) estimated execution time = "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 3464.

STAGE 2 (IXSCAN) estimated execution time = "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 3251.

So 6715 ms spent on the 2 STAGES.

Where was the remaining 10860 ms execution time spent?  I cannot work it out, and the execution stats don't tell me either

This is mongodb version 4.2, running on Linux

Comment: [explain.executionStats.executionTimeMillis](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/index.html#explain.executionStats.executionTimeMillis) is defined as "Total time in milliseconds required for query plan selection _and_ query execution."; it may be the two actions's combined total.

Comment: Thanks.  But I don't anticipate the query plan selection to take any time at all.  There were no rejected plans, so plan selection should be fast.  Maybe the estimates are completely wrong, but that's what I'm trying to ascertain.